# Is there a module to create a list of favorite nodes?

Tags: 7

I am looking for module that would let users of a site save nodes as Favorite, so that these nodes can be found back later via a "My favorite" interface.

Has anyone heard about such a module?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks to find, recommend, or suggest hosting providers, tools, modules, themes, distributions, books, tutorials, documentation, or other off-site resources.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was thinking that would be a great idea, until I remembered that Drupal contributors have already offered quite a few solutions for this as demonstrated by a quick search of the Drupal site. Of course, [Flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag) module provides a great abstract way of creating these types of systems. There's also [Favorites](http://drupal.org/project/favorites) and [Add to favorites](http://drupal.org/project/addfavorites), but those are for Drupal 6 only right now. I would recommend Flag I think just because I've used it for precisely this type of thing as have many others (even though it's still in beta), and *quicksketch* and *fago* are great Drupal developers.

Comment: Flag is definitely a great module with a very well made documentation, thanks again for the link..

Answer (score 1):

It is worth mentioning that you can do this with the [Node Queue module](http://drupal.org/project/nodequeue).

For your particular scenario, you would also need [Smart Queue per User](http://drupal.org/project/smartqueue_users), but unfortunately [that is still being ported to Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/1255904). There's a [sandbox version of the project](http://drupal.org/sandbox/vegantriathlete/1386510) available to work with, though.

Comment: Why would you chose this solution over Flags?

Answer (score 0):

[Voting API](http://drupal.org/project/votingapi) is the way to go, you can use a module like [Rate](http://drupal.org/project/rate) with a custom widget.

Comment: I have no idea why someone down voted this answer. If a down vote is cast, a reason should be given. +1 - learned about the Rate module